# How to get R function to return object of correct class (I can do it but must be a better way)

Tags: r, function

I'm writing my first R function, tax_glom.named(). In brief, I want it to return an object of the same class as the input, but can't seem to do it without clunkily assigning the variable to itself (`phy.glom <- phy.glom`) and figure there must be a better way.

`phy` is a phyloseq object from the phyloseq package
`tax.rank` is a taxonomic rank, like "Phylum"
The functions tax_glom() and tax_table() are in the phyloseq package.

```
tax_glom.named <- function(phy, tax.rank) {
  phy.glom <- tax_glom(phy, tax.rank)     
  names <- as.data.frame(tax_table(phy))[taxa_names(phy.glom),tax.rank]
  taxa_names(phy.glom) <- names
  phy.glom <- phy.glom
}
```

The goal is to return an object of class phyloseq. It works correctly as is.

```
> temp <- tax_glom.named(gi.16S.r4750, "Phylum")
> class(temp)
[1] "phyloseq"
attr(,"package")
[1] "phyloseq"
```

But if I use the same function but get rid of the last line `phy.glom <- phy.glom` the returned object is a factor instead of phyloseq.

I know the code is probably pretty opaque, but I'm hoping this question is answerable without knowing the details of the steps: Is the line `phy.glom <- phy.glom` the right way to do it, or is there a better way?

SOLVED: `return(phy.glom)` is the way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried `class(phy.glom) <- class(phy)`?

Comment: Or just `return(phy.glom)`? Without explicitly returning your result your function might not return the right object.

Comment: @Marius Yes, thanks. `return(phy.glom)` worked...as seems very obvious now.